# how to run .war with java to execute inside dir from desktop shortcut

Tags: bash, java, ubuntu-20.04

This is my case. I have a .war that I execute with java and it only works inside its folder:

```
cd /opt/myappdir/
java -jar myapp.war
```

Note: It does not work like that:

```
java -jar /opt/myappdir/myapp.war
```

I have created a bash script (`sudo /opt/myappdir/run.sh`) to launch this command

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /opt/myappdir/
java -jar myapp.war
```

**So far everything works. Now the problem:**

I want to launch it from a shortcut on my desktop. This is my desktop shortcut to start myapp war

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=MyApp
Comment=Run MyApp
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/myappdir/run.sh
Icon=/opt/myappdir/myapp.ico
Path=/opt/myappdir/
Terminal=false
```

But since `myapp.war` needs to be run with sudo and inside the `myappdir` I modified my `run.sh` script as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /opt/myappdir/
dir=$(dirname $(readlink -m $BASH_SOURCE))
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 java -jar myapp.war
```

Why line with `dir=$(dirname $(readlink -m $BASH_SOURCE))`?

because I need to make sure `myapp.war` is running inside `myappdir`

Why line with `pkexec`?

because when double clicking the desktop shortcut `java` needs to be run with `sudo`

out:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile myapp.war
```

someone [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1206765/828892) offers a solution to a similar question, but it didn't work for me. (Modifying the proposal:)

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=java -jar 'myapp.war'
Path=/opt/myappdir/
Name=myapp
Comment=myapp
Icon=/opt/myappdir/myapp.ico
```

how can i fix my `run.sh` script to run `myapp.war` with `sudo` inside `myappdir`, and call it from desktop shortcut? Thanks

Update

According to what someone explains [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35974482/8747573), `pkexec` does not run in the same directory (I guess that's the reason why it can't find `myapp.war` file). So the solution could be to run a command that would force it into the directory to run java, but I've tried and failed

Comment: How about adding `Path=/opt/myappdir` key in .desktop file? From the desktop file specification, regarding path key: «if entry is of type Application, the working directory to run the program in».

Comment: @Krackout i have tested and nothing happen. same out. The problem is still `run.sh`